cardano-cli query leadership-schedule DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure "expected word16"
I have been using cardano-cli query leadership-schedule every epoch for years, but now it has failed with this:

Command failed: query leadership-schedule  Error: Failed to successfully decode the current epoch state: DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure "EpochState (ConwayEra StandardCrypto)" (DeserialiseFailure 2123242835 "expected word16")

Any idea what caused this?

This appears to be a mismatched node and CLI version.
Can you try with these versions?
cardano-node --version
cardano-node 9.1.1 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev efd560070aaf042d1eb4680ae37fc607c7742319
cardano-cli --version
cardano-cli 9.2.1.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev efd560070aaf042d1eb4680ae37fc607c7742319
Also, please ensure you're using cardano-cli conway query leadership-schedule as the default is babbage era and mainnet is no longer in babbage.

Works now after updating the node version and updating the comand with "conway". Thanks!
Previously I was using:
cardano-node 9.1.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 176f99e51155cb3eaa0711db1c3c969d67438958
cardano-cli 9.2.1.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 176f99e51155cb3eaa0711db1c3c969d67438958
